# Recursive function returns sum, struggling to understand why?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

The following function was given to me on a review sheet:

```
(define mystery(lambda(m n)
                 (cond
                   ((= m 0) n)
                   ((= n 0) m)
                   (#t (+ 2(mystery(- m 1)(- n 1))))
                   )))
```

The first two conditions are simple, it's just the recursive `otherwise` that's confusing me. It just seems to me that the recursion will continue until they both equal zero, which certainly doesn't return the sum. Can someone provide an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the best way is not to nest but to precompute. Looking at the base case we test with either zero:

```scm
(mystery 0 2) ; ==> 2
(nystery 3 0) ; ==> 3
```

Thus every time at least one argument is zero it returns the other argument. Lets try with a non zero value and remember the second you see a value we have already done before you just switch it with its result:

```scm
(mystery 1 3)        ; ==
(+ 2 (mystery 0 2))  ; == (we switch known value)
(+ 2 2)                        
; ==> 4 

(mystery 4 1)       ; == (we substitute with the expression)
(+ 2 (mystery 3 0)) ; == (we switch known value)
(+ 2 3) 
; ==> 5
```

Since we know the base case always returns the other value we don't need to precalculate it. Here is a go that does that:

```scm
(mystery 3 9)                  ; == (we substitute with the expression)
(+ 2 (mystery 2 8)             ; == (we substitute with the expression)
(+ 2 (+ 2 (mystery 1 7)))      ; == (we substitute with the expression)
(+ 2 (+ 2 (+ 2 (mystery 0 6))) ; == (we substitute with the expression, n, which is 6)
(+ 2 (+ 2 (+ 2 6)))            ; == (we substitute (+ 2 6))
(+ 2 (+ 2 8))                  ; == (we substitute (+ 2 8))
(+ 2 10)                       ; == (we substitute (+ 2 10)
; ==> 12
```

We can generalize what will happen. The lowest of `n` and `m` will decide when the recursion ends. At each step it will add 2 and recurse. Thus it is a fancy way of making:

```scm
(define (double-min n m)
 (let ((vmin (min n m))
       (vmax (max n m)))
   (+ (* 2 vmin) (- vmax vmin))))
```

Which again is a fancy way of adding the two numbers since if `n > m`, then `2*m+(n-m) = m+m+(n-m) = m+n`

Comment: This answer is wrong and hard to follow. `(mystery 0 <something>)` should be `<something>`, not `0`. `mystery` implements addition as the question title implies, not "double-min".

Comment: @jerry Mystery, as in the OPs code, does **not** implement addition. If either `n` or `m` are zero then the results is zero. The default case adds 2 and the result from the recursion with both arguments reduced by one. Thus the base case is when the smallest of the two are zero making the function compute the double of the smallest of it's arguments. Thus `(* 2 (min n m))`. Using precomputed values to substitute is the easiest way to reason about pure recursive functions.

Comment: @Sylwester When either argument is `0`, the other argument is returned, not the `0` argument. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding something, it's addition. I'm pretty sure `(mystery 5 1)` would be `6`, not `2`. I will actually run it and verify.

Comment: @jerry OMG you're right. I didn't catch that the base case returned the other argument that was perhaps not zero. Updated. And thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's format the code a bit better to see what's happening:

```
(define (mystery m n)
  (cond ((= m 0) n)
        ((= n 0) m)
        (else (+ 2 (mystery (- m 1) (- n 1))))))
```

Now, remember that a `cond` executes only the action corresponding to the first condition that is `true` (from top to bottom), the others are ignored. If none of the conditions is `true`, then the `else` part is executed. The important thing to remember is that only one action is executed.

In particular, your `mystery` procedure will stop when *either* `m` or `n` becomes zero, not when *both* become zero. When one of the two reaches zero, the recursion starts to unwind, returning the sum. You can see this when tracing the execution - for example, in Racket:

```
(require racket/trace)
(trace mystery)
(mystery 3 2)

>(mystery 3 2)
> (mystery 2 1)
> >(mystery 1 0)
< <1
< 3
<5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate on Óscar López's answer (I can't format this in a comment): I find that it's often useful to write these sorts of little recursive maths functions down as if they were maths:

Let m and n be natural numbers, then

- n + m = n if m = 0;
- n + m = m if n = 0;
- n + m = n - 1 + m - 1 + 2;
- there are no other cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define mystery(lambda(m n)
                 (cond
                   ((= m 0) n)
                   ((= n 0) m)
                   (#t (+ 2 (mystery (- m 1) (- n 1))))
                   )))
```

First and second conditions are obvious.

Explanation of how the third statement is working:

> 1 each is taken out of m and n and kept as 2 outside this function.
>   This is continued till either m is 0 or n is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 cases are obvious, the sum of 2 numbers where one of the numbers is 0, is equal to the other number.

In the last case, after checking the arguments for 0, we know for sure that both of them are non-0. *Assuming* that mystery returns the sum of its 2 arguments, then

```
(+ 2 (mystery (- arg1 1) (- arg2 1)))
```

will return a sum that is equal to `(mystery arg1 arg2)` and will eventually halt when one of the arguments is 0, returning the desired result.

Assuming that mystery returns the sum of its 2 arguments is key here and is called the *recursive leap of faith*. (Google it)